# How to pass docker swarm manager token to worker nodes in AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, docker-swarm, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a Docker Swarm cluster using Terraform, I created 1 manager and 3 worker nodes. I installed Docker and initiated the Docker Swarm and created the manager token.

How can I forward the key from my manager to worker nodes, all the servers running in AWS, and running the `terrafrom apply` command on my local machine?

I have multiple restrictions, as I can't request for new services for this particular task.

Sorry failed to mention, I have to use Dynamic IP as the entire environment is build using dynamic IP and no IP locked to any specific resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swarm manager needs a way of passing the worker token to the workers once it has initialised. The best way to do that would be to have the swarm manager's userdata trigger generating the token and putting it into a shared store that they can both access. The simplest thing for this in AWS would be to use [AWS SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) which allows you to store smallish strings optionally encrypted and backed by normal IAM permissions.

You would need to give the swarm manager instance permission via an IAM instance profile to write a token to something like `/swarm/token/worker` and then allow the worker instances permission to read that same token.

Then in your manager's userdata script you'd want to have something like:

```sh
WORKER_TOKEN=$(docker swarm join-token worker)
aws ssm put-parameter --region us-west-2 --name '/swarm/token/worker' --type SecureString --value "${WORKER_TOKEN}"
```

In your worker's userdata script you'd then want to have the equivalent read and execute:

```sh
WORKER_TOKEN=$(aws ssm get-parameter --region us-west-2 --name '/swarm/token/worker' --with-decryption --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
eval "${WORKER_TOKEN}"
```

There is also a [community module that has an example of how to run Docker Swarm on AWS](https://github.com/trajano/terraform-docker-swarm-aws) that relies on putting the secret token into S3 and then retrieving it on the worker node with the userdata script. That may give you more tips on how to get a Swarm cluster running nicely on AWS.

Comment: Many thanks for the above suggestion, Unfortunately I can't bring in SSM to create the Docker Swarm as I only have limited access and can't request to provision for this task. I read through the code in community module may be I will find something that I can invoke in our code.

Comment: Can you use S3? It's not particularly well suited to this but people have been using it for this purpose since before SSM parameter store and for objects larger than 4kb.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR, I guess the S3 would be the right option for me to go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem with these steps:

- Static ip to master node in `AWS`.
- I created simple api rest app in `nodejs` that runs on master server. This `api` accepts request from other nodes and returns token key.

This is essential code that I use:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

    const execFunction = (command, res, returnOutput) => {
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (stdout) {
                returnOutput ? res.status(200).send(stdout) : res.sendStatus(204);
            }
            else if (stderr) {
                res.status(400).send({ error: stderr });
            }
            else if (error !== null) {
                res.status(400).send({ error: error });
            }
            else {
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
        });
    };

    app.get("/api/dockerswarm/token/:type", (req, res) => {
        const { type } = req.params;

        if (!type || (type !== "worker" && type !== "manager")) {
            res.status(400).send({ message: 'invalid token type supplied (manager|worker)' });
        }
        else {
            const dockerCommand = `docker swarm join-token ${type} | sed -n 3p | grep -Po 'docker swarm join --token \\K[^\\s]*'`;
            execFunction(dockerCommand, res, true);
        }
    });
```

Now other machine can request token to master node and can connect to Swarm (I inserted code in userdata that checks if node is already in Swarm, otherwise requests token).

[Here](https://github.com/sbraer/AwsNodeJsCodeDeploy) complete code (include some other files that I use in my AWS Swarm).

Comment: Thanks @VersilioB unfortunately I can't go ahead request for Static IP for the master as the entire environment is build using dynamic IP. As mentioned above I have either use S3 to store the key and call in my worker nodes or have to use remote_exec to capture the output and use it in worker nodes else consider using ansible for the Docker Swarm cluster setup

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share what I'm using on my end here.

The general concept is that the 1'st node becomes a manager and registers its join tokens in ssm. (Probably should be encrypted but this is our dev script)

Additional nodes will enter a loop where they try to pull the token down and register with the swarm - if that doesn't work they'll drop into a sleep and try again.

#### Ressource Definition

```
resource "aws_instance" "swarm" {
  ami           = "ami-0cff7528ff583bf9a"
  instance_type = "t2.small"

  count = var.swarm_manager_node_count + var.swarm_worker_node_count

  key_name = "MY-SSH-KEY"

  vpc_security_group_ids = var.swarm_security_group_ids
  subnet_id              = var.swarm_subnet_id


  tags = {
    Name = "swarm-node-${count.index}"
  }

  # Use a file template to configure the user_data
  # by declaring vars we can inject these into the final script
  # that will be run.
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.tftpl", {
    node_number                 = count.index
    node_name                   = "swarm-node-${count.index}"
    WORKER_TOKEN                = ""
    MANAGER_TOKEN               = ""
    SWARM_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = var.aws_access_key_id
    SWARM_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = var.aws_secret_access_key
    SWARM_AWS_REGION            = "us-east-1"
    SWARM_MANAGER_NODE_COUNT    = var.swarm_manager_node_count
    }
  )
}
```

#### user_data

I have a script `user_data.tftpl`

```bash
#!/bin/bash -xe

# Install the docker
yum update -y

# install Docker
yum install docker -y

# add ec2-user to docker group
usermod -a -G docker ec2-user

# Start / enable docker
systemctl enable docker.service
systemctl start docker.service


# If we are NODE0 we are a manager

echo ${node_number}
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${SWARM_AWS_REGION}
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${SWARM_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${SWARM_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}


aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${SWARM_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${SWARM_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
aws configure set default_region ${SWARM_AWS_REGION}

if [[ "${node_number}" == "0" ]]; then
    docker swarm init
    export MANAGER_TOKEN=$(docker swarm join-token manager | grep token | xargs echo -n)
    export WORKER_TOKEN=$(docker swarm join-token worker | grep token | xargs echo -n)

    echo "Storing Manager Token [$MANAGER_TOKEN]"
    echo "Storing Worker Token [$WORKER_TOKEN]"

    aws ssm put-parameter \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --name '/swarm/token/worker' \
    --type String \
    --overwrite \
    --value "$WORKER_TOKEN"

    aws ssm put-parameter \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --name '/swarm/token/manager' \
    --type String \
    --overwrite \
    --value "$MANAGER_TOKEN"
elif [[ "${node_number}" -le "${SWARM_MANAGER_NODE_COUNT}" ]]; then

    JOIN_STATUS=1
    while [ $JOIN_STATUS -ne 0 ]; do
        docker swarm leave || true
        $(aws ssm get-parameter \
        --region us-east-1 \
        --name '/swarm/token/manager' \
        --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
        JOIN_STATUS=$?
        echo $JOIN_STATUS was

        if [[ $JOIN_STATUS -ne 0 ]]; then
            echo "Unable to join swarm ... retrying in 10 seconds"
            sleep 10
        else
            echo "Maybe the join worked?"
        fi
    done
else
    JOIN_STATUS=1
    while [ $JOIN_STATUS -ne 0 ]; do
        docker swarm leave || true
        $(aws ssm get-parameter \
        --region us-east-1 \
        --name '/swarm/token/worker' \
        --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
        JOIN_STATUS=$?
        if [[ $JOIN_STATUS -ne 0 ]]; then
            echo "Unable to join swarm ... retrying in 10 seconds"
            sleep 10
        else
            echo "Maybe the join worked?"
        fi
    done
fi
```

I haven't run into any major issues yet...